# Can <hr> be nested in Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, image

I want a simple dividing line beneath my floated images.

My stylesheet reads thus:

```
img.floatrightclear {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Can a colored line be displayed below the image, at the same width of the image?  Can it be included in the image css?

Comment: you can style <hr> in css. see this for example: https://codepen.io/ibrahimjabbari/pen/ozinB

Comment: you could use a `border`.

Comment: add padding-bottom and border-bottom to show a border below the image at some distance.

Comment: If you only need the line to stretch the width of the image, then you can the border trick others mention.  If you need the line to stretch further across the screen, then you would need to use an `<hr>` element separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use some padding on the bottom and then apply a border only to the bottom

```
padding-bottom:50px;
border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; /*Whatever color code you wanted the <hr> to be
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h57dfcmt/

Answer (score 0):

As Nawed Khan says, just use a border-bottom and padding-bottom, like so:

```
img.floatrightclear {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  padding-bottom: 10px; /* the distance between bottom and line */
  border-bottom: 2px solid black; /* The line */
}
```